# Adding Endpoints Support for Android Clients

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

Before explaining my problem I would like to compliment you on your website, very useful for us developers. I apologize for the inconvenience but I do not know how to solve this problem:

My target is to create a project with Endpoint support for an Android app. I used the following guide: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-android

Since I'm creating a new Android app, I followed the first way suggested: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae

I followed this last guide step by step; but I found several errors in Eclipse that I don't know how to resolve.

After i used the wizard in Eclipse: **File > New > Other > Google > App Engine Connected Android Project**

In package explorer appeared two project:

1. CloudTest
2. CloudTest-AppEngine

Particurarly, in the class **GCMIntentService** located in CloudTest, Eclipse reports three import errors:

1. import com.cloudtest.deviceinfoendpoint.Deviceinfoendpoint;
2. import com.cloudtest.deviceinfoendpoint.Deviceinfoendpoint.Builder;
3. import com.cloudtest.deviceinfoendpoint.model.DeviceInfo;

Eclipse reports that can not solve the imports!! My question is why? What's wrong?

For build this project I downloaded:

1. The latest Google Plugin for Eclipse
2. The latest Android Development Tools
3. The latest Google App Engine SDK for Java
4. The latest Eclipse version
5. The latest Google APIs
6. The latest Java sdk
7. The latest Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library

Sorry to bother you but do not know where I'm wrong. 
Waiting for your kind reply a, I thank you and Best regards.

Comment: is your "CloudTest" project incluiding the CloudTest-AppEngine build path?
that could be missing and thats why all the package is not recognized!!!